# How does changing key photo in Live photo differ from burst mode?

Tags: iphone, photos

I notice when using Live photos you can change the key photo if you want. Is there any quality loss based on doing this? How does this differ from taking Burst mode photos? Is there a difference in how the camera (focus/aperature etc) behaves?

Does this function mean that if I have Live photos enabled there's no technical reason to use Burst mode (other than perhaps more control over how long to capture images for?)

Answer (score 2):

Changing the key photo of a Live Photo is not a replacement for burst mode in terms of quality.

- [The video segment of a Live Photo is 960×720](https://www.macrumors.com/2015/09/22/iphone6s-live-photos-file-details/), which is a huge drop in resolution.
- [Burst mode takes full resolution photos.](https://9to5mac.com/2013/10/07/camera-ios-app-adds-full-resolution-burst-mode-new-ios-7-filter-pack/)

Comment: I saw elsewhere comments that changing the keyframe didn't seem to result in any loss of resolution/quality.. so I wonder if the resolution of live photos has been increased. I think the ability to select keyframe was added in a later update but I'm not finding details