# Does taking live photos store a redundant MOV file?

Tags: iphone, photos, heic

On my iPhone, when I backup my photos with [photosync](https://www.photosync-app.com/home.html), I notice that I get two files for every live photo.  One HEIC and one MOV.  Eg:

```
Recents/IMG_0941.HEIC
Recents/IMG_0941.MOV
Recents/IMG_0942.HEIC
Recents/IMG_0942.Mov
```

What's not clear to me is if this is redundant or just a quirk of photosync.

Is this something the IPhone itself is doing (storing two files on the iphone) or is it likely that photo sync is extracting the MOV file itself?

Are the two files redundant (can I delete the MOV and get back to it from just the HEIC file?)

Comment: How many physical camera lenses does your iPhone have?

Comment: @bmike why does that make a difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is **not** redundant. Live Photos consist of an high-res image and a video (lower quality than the image).

- The `HEIC` (*High Efficiency Image Codec*) format is only for images, and it's the one when you actually hit the exposure button.
- The `.MOV` files are displayed when you long press the photo.

Therefore you can extract the single `HEIC` image from the `MOV` file (with lower quality though), while you can't turn the single image into a video. This also means, this is something the iPhone is doing and not photo sync. You would also get those files when using AirDrop for example.

---

Note: Since the video is lower quality than a single image, changing the key frame *must* change the quality. However, I could imagine (this is speculation though) that Apple might use some ML/smart algorithm to make the new key frame look better (similar to something like night mode, where a lot of processing happens).

---

Sources:

- [How does changing key photo in Live photo differ from burst mode?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/303315/how-does-changing-key-photo-in-live-photo-differ-from-burst-mode)
- [Live Photos Called 'Best New Feature,' Composed of Separate JPG and MOV Files](https://www.macrumors.com/2015/09/22/iphone6s-live-photos-file-details/)
- [Apple Live Photo file format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32508375/apple-live-photo-file-format) on SO
- [Live Photo Quality Loss When Changing Key Frame](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/250580900) on Apple forums

Comment: So does that mean selecting a different key frame in the photos app produces a lower quality photo?

Comment: I edited my answer to include that info: the highest quality image is the original key frame.