What are the dimensions of the live video (*.MOV) file that accompanies a live photo?
I'm trying to find the video dimensions (height and width) for the short live video clip that accompanies an iPhone live photo. I downloaded photos from iCloud and see that live photos have both a JPEG and MOV extension. For example,
IMG_6010.JPEG
IMG_6010.MOV

Normally I can see the dimensions of a photo or video by looking at the properties or the file but when I open the *.MOV file I do not see any dimensions listed.
What are the video dimensions of the live videos from a live photo?
For a the JPEG example above, the JPEG dimensions are:

But the MOV file shows nothing for the video properties

Searching for a solution
I searched for "what is the resolution of the live *.mov file associated with applies iphone photos" and got some results but no answer:

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/250509850?sortBy=best - Live Photos are lower resolution that photo.

Does taking live photos store a redundant MOV file?


Next, I'll look for applications that might show this information.

If you open it in VLC does it show you dimensions then? VLC usually will have ALL the metadata on a video file

It’s not entirely clear what problem you’re facing here. Each phone has different lenses and settings and why would the dimensions same between them. On what computer and OS are you downloading files? Is this more about how to process the files on a specific computer?

Something in the process of transfering the photos/videos onto your computer must have gone wrong. The mentioned resolutions are not correct. iPhones these days have 12/48MP and that is someting in the realms of 4200x2800 for the 12MP  photo.

I used iCloud to download the photo/videos.  I tested with a single photo and found that the original image (shown in iCloud) is 12MP  4032 x 3024 as you stated it should be.   However, after downloading the image, the photo size was 3MB 2048 x 1536.  As for the live video *.MOV file, https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/410879/197238 says that the *.MOV files are stored in a lower resolution quality than the photo.  So the *.MOV is only at 960x720.

I just also noticed that my iPhone videos (on iCloud) are 1080 x 1920 resolution but after download they are only 720 x 1280 (sigh)

@PatS I have rolled back the edit (containing the answer) and reopened the question, so that it can now accept answers. Consider posting the solution as an answer in the answer section.

Use macOS to inspect quicktime files. Windows explorer may not be able to correctly parse the VUI info.

The program mediainfo can be used to extract/display the resolution of the *.MOV file. For example, when the SO ran it, it outputted:
General
Complete name                            : IMG_6513.MOV
Format                                   : MPEG-4
Format profile                           : QuickTime
Codec ID                                 : qt   0000.00 (qt  )
File size                                : 1.42 MiB
Duration                                 : 2 s 767 ms
Overall bit rate                         : 4 298 kb/s
Encoded date                             : UTC 2024-07-09 00:29:18
Tagged date                              : UTC 2024-07-09 00:29:19
Writing library                          : Apple QuickTime
com.apple.quicktime.location.accuracy.ho : 4.738770
com.apple.quicktime.live-photo.auto      : 1
com.apple.quicktime.content.identifier   : BD8FFBE0-2F5C-4CC2-A457-74A73C2476DC
com.apple.quicktime.live-photo.vitality- : 0.940
com.apple.quicktime.live-photo.vitality- : 4
com.apple.quicktime.location.ISO6709     : +90.000-00.0000+100.801/
com.apple.quicktime.make                 : Apple
com.apple.quicktime.model                : iPhone 14 Pro
com.apple.quicktime.software             : 17.5.1
com.apple.quicktime.creationdate         : 2024-07-08T20:15:34-0400

Video
ID                                       : 2
Format                                   : AVC
Format/Info                              : Advanced Video Codec
Format profile                           : High@L3.1
Format settings                          : CABAC / 2 Ref Frames
Format settings, CABAC                   : Yes
Format settings, Reference frames        : 2 frames
Codec ID                                 : avc1
Codec ID/Info                            : Advanced Video Coding
Duration                                 : 2 s 767 ms
Bit rate                                 : 4 183 kb/s
Width                                    : 960 pixels
Clean aperture width                     : 872 pixels
Height                                   : 720 pixels
Clean aperture height                    : 654 pixels
Display aspect ratio                     : 4:3
Frame rate mode                          : Constant
Frame rate                               : 30.000 FPS
Color space                              : YUV
Chroma subsampling                       : 4:2:0
Bit depth                                : 8 bits
Scan type                                : Progressive
Bits/(Pixel*Frame)                       : 0.202
Stream size                              : 1.38 MiB (97%)
Title                                    : Core Media Video
Encoded date                             : UTC 2024-07-09 00:29:18
Tagged date                              : UTC 2024-07-09 00:29:19
Color range                              : Full
Color primaries                          : BT.709
Transfer characteristics                 : BT.709
Matrix coefficients                      : BT.709
Codec configuration box                  : avcC

Audio
ID                                       : 1
Format                                   : AAC LC
Format/Info                              : Advanced Audio Codec Low Complexity
Codec ID                                 : mp4a-40-2
Duration                                 : 2 s 767 ms
Source duration                          : 2 s 833 ms
Bit rate mode                            : Constant
Bit rate                                 : 60.7 kb/s
Nominal bit rate                         : 64.0 kb/s
Channel(s)                               : 1 channel
Channel layout                           : C
Sampling rate                            : 44.1 kHz
Frame rate                               : 43.066 FPS (1024 SPF)
Compression mode                         : Lossy
Stream size                              : 20.5 KiB (1%)
Source stream size                       : 20.9 KiB (1%)
Title                                    : Core Media Audio
Encoded date                             : UTC 2024-07-09 00:29:18
Tagged date                              : UTC 2024-07-09 00:29:19

Other #1
Type                                     : meta
Duration                                 : 2 s 767 ms

Other #2
Type                                     : meta
Duration                                 : 2 s 767 ms

Other #3
Type                                     : meta
Duration                                 : 1 s 235 ms
Source duration                          : 2 ms
Stream size                              : 76.0 KiB
Source stream size                       : 105 Bytes

(Based on this comment)
Instructions on how to install mediainfo can be found here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28671798/how-to-get-media-info-when-playing-with-vlc-player


As suggested in this comment, use VLC to get the dimensions.
VLC shows the following metadata which answers the question:

Image shared by author of the question.
The video is at 960x720 on an iPhone 14.
The video resolution might vary depending on the camera (iPhone/iPad) used, which the author stated they didn't consider when asking the question.

There are tools specifically built to inspect media files, like mediainfo and ffprobe.
